# Service workers and page performance

Tags: javascript, image, performance, http, service-worker

I'm stuck at a wedding reception that I really don't want to be at and I'm driving, so obviously I'm reading about service workers. I'm on my phone so can't play about with anything but was thinking if they're a viable option for improving page performance?

Images are the biggest killer on my site and I'm half thinking we could use a service worker to cache them to help get page load times down. From what I can tell, the browser still makes the http request, it's just the response is from the SW cache, not the file location. Am I missing something here? Is there therefore any actual benefit to doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the regular http cache has a lot of overlap with ServiceWorker cache, one thing that the former can't handle very well is the dynamically generated html used in many client-side javascript applications.
Even when all the resources of the app are cache hits, there is still the delay as the javascript is compiled and executed before the app is usable.

Addy Osmani has [demonstrated how ServiceWorker can be used to cache the Shell of an app.](https://addyosmani.com/blog/application-shell/) When the DOM is modified on the client, it is updated in the cache. The next time that URL is requested, the ServiceWorker replies with html that is ready for use before the app has booted.

The other advantage regards [lie-fi](https://youtu.be/d5_6yHixpsQ?t=6m38s): when it seems the network is available, but not enough packets are getting through. ServiceWorkers can afford to have a near-imperceptible timeout, because they can serve immediately from cache **and** wait for the response to load (if ever).

Answer (score 0):

Your consideration is invalid.

Service worker is designed to work like a proxy server that can especially handle some off-page operations like offline ability, push notification, background synchronization, etc. So in your case, you will gain no performance benefits by caching images with service worker over the traditional browser's cache approach.

Comment: I suspected as much. I really want to sit and dig into them more. Thanks

Comment: For anyone reading this now, MDN actually suggests using service workers for image preloading: "Performance enhancements, for example pre-fetching resources that the user is likely to need in the near future, such as the next few pictures in a photo album." – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API#other_use_case_ideas